# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the above error in the last line of code ,I have tried answers but that doesnt seems to work

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $name = $_SESSION["username"];
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));

    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT  `logintime` FROM `attendance` WHERE empid=? AND date_t=?");
    $statement->bind_param("ss", $name, $today);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($logintime);
    while ($statement->fetch()) {

    }
    $logintime = new DateTime($logintime);

    $interval = $logintime->diff($time);

    $hours = $interval->format('%h');
    $minutes = $interval->format('%i');
    $workinghours = $hours + $minutes / 60;


    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `attendance` SET `logouttime`=? ,`workinghours`=?  WHERE empid=? AND date_t=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $time, $workinghours, $name, $today);
    $run = $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: at last line $run=$stmt->execute()

Comment: you have to use the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method

Comment: And to how to do that?? @Scuzzy

Comment: What are these "answers" that you have tried? Please explain that in your question. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#107757) method to convert your DateTime object into something MySQL can use.

```
date_format($time,'Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

or

```
$time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

So...

```
$timeAsString = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$timeAsString,$workinghours,$name,$today);
```

Comment: its is giving me an error only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: glad to have helped