# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in line 364

Tags: php, mysql

[this is my line 364](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw9u5.png)

```
    $fcreacion  = date_create($row['fechacreacion'].' '.$row['horacreacion']);
    $fecharesolucion = date_create($row['fecharesolucion'].' '.$row['horaresolucion']); 
    if($fecharesolucion == ''){
        $fecharesolucion = date('Y-m-d');
    }
    echo $fcreacion.'-'.$fecharesolucion;
    $interval = date_diff($fcreacion, $fecharesolucion);
    $dif = $interval->format('%d d %h h');
```

Good night, could someone give me a hand with this error that I do not understand well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251508/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate two `DateTime` objects, not Strings. You must convert it by using [`DateTime::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) as follows:

```
echo $fcreacion->format('Y-m-d').'-'.$fecharesolucion->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Hello I did the commented, but I get this error now in the same modified line  Call to a member function format() on string in

Comment: Is possible that the problem does happen when you create $fecharesolucion in the cases it was empty? Try checking if applying data_create at the assignation works:  $fecharesolucion = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));

Comment: work but i get this error now Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in line  422 this is mi condition   if ($row['fecharesolucion']!='') {
   $xfecharesolucion = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $row['fecharesolucion']);
   $xfecharesolucion = date_format($xfecharesolucion, "m/d/Y");
  } and my line 422 is this $xfecharesolucion = date_format($xfecharesolucion, "m/d/Y");

Comment: I think that this is another issue as the code does not correspond with the original. Please mark the first one as closed and look for the new one through the site.